# linux: Permission denied although having permissions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, permissions, seafile-server

I am trying to install Seafile but there occurs an strange error.
I create a group and user named seafile to do all stuff, but I can't run my owned shell scripts:

```
[09:24] seafile@raspberrypi /media/fa36508a-b3c4-4499-b30a-711dd5994225/seaf/seafile-server-5.0.4 >ll
total 108K
drwxr-xr-x  6 seafile seafile 1.0K Jan 25 13:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 seafile seafile 1.0K Feb 11 09:20 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 seafile seafile  11K Jan 25 13:53 check_init_admin.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 seafile seafile 2.0K Jan 25 13:53 reset-admin.sh
drwxr-xr-x  2 seafile seafile 1.0K Jan 25 13:53 runtime
-rwxr-xr-x  1 seafile seafile 1.9K Jan 25 13:53 seaf-fsck.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 seafile seafile 3.3K Jan 25 13:53 seaf-fuse.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 seafile seafile 2.8K Jan 25 13:53 seaf-gc.sh
drwxr-xr-x  5 seafile seafile 1.0K Jan 25 13:58 seafile
-rwxr-xr-x  1 seafile seafile 4.7K Jan 25 13:53 seafile.sh
drwxr-xr-x 12 seafile seafile 1.0K Jan 24 18:47 seahub
-rwxr-xr-x  1 seafile seafile 7.1K Jan 25 13:53 seahub.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 seafile seafile  44K Jan 25 13:53 setup-seafile-mysql.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 seafile seafile 2.7K Jan 25 13:53 setup-seafile-mysql.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 seafile seafile  20K Jan 25 13:53 setup-seafile.sh
drwxr-xr-x  4 seafile seafile 1.0K Jan 24 14:15 upgrade
[09:24] seafile@raspberrypi /media/fa36508a-b3c4-4499-b30a-711dd5994225/seaf/seafile-server-5.0.4 >./setup-seafile.sh
bash: ./setup-seafile.sh: Permission denied
[09:24] seafile@raspberrypi /media/fa36508a-b3c4-4499-b30a-711dd5994225/seaf/seafile-server-5.0.4 >chmod +x setup-seafile.sh
[09:25] seafile@raspberrypi /media/fa36508a-b3c4-4499-b30a-711dd5994225/seaf/seafile-server-5.0.4 >./setup-seafile.sh
bash: ./setup-seafile.sh: Permission denied
```

**SOLVED** Problem was the noexec flag at mounting

Comment: what happen when you set it to 777?

Comment: and can u try "ls -z" command to see what it shows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421842/permission-issues-not-able-to-run-script-as-root/17423164#17423164

Comment: @123 I'm user seafile

Comment: @Mox There is no difference with 777. And 'ls -z' outputs: invalid option -- 'z'